# What happens if I have a container running on image:latest and I push new image that is also image:latest

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops

I'm new to the devOps space and I'm just wondering what would happen if I set up a compute instance or kubernetes instance on Google Cloud with the `latest` tag and I pushed an image with the same name and tag e.g. `image:latest`. I'm just trying to figure out what the best way to setup automated deployments is through something like CircleCI or Codeship

Will this cause:

**Non-cluster compute instance**

1. Restart container using the newly pushed image with tag `latest`
2. Restart container using newly pushed image with tag `latest` only when the container is stopped / restarted
3. Do absolutely nothing

**Cluster / Kubernetes instance**

1. Create an "image update update request" in queue
2. Do nothing

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing a new `latest` tag on an image replaces the previous `latest` tag. It won't cause an automatic container restart (unless you configure your CI/CD system to do so).

While useful for development, I avoid using the `latest` tag for non-development work. It can introduce surprises and ambiguity that you don't want if a container is restarted unexpectedly.